# How to make a fingerprint of Chrome 79 using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, user-agent

I tried this line of code and it didn't work:

```
option.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36")
```

The fingerprint shown on selenium is the same as in google chrome. Please help me out! I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think it'll suffice as it's only one line of code.

Comment: if you're talking about a browser fingerprint, it's built from much more than just a user agent.  That part of it is likely to be disregarded depending on the use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set any of the supported [user-agent](/questions/tagged/user-agent) of ***Chrome v79*** using the `execute_cdp_cmd()` command as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
  print("Default UserAgent is: "+driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;"))

  # Setting user agent as Chrome/79.0.3945.36
  driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; Generic Android-x86_64 Build/QD1A.190821.014.C2; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/79.0.3945.36 Safari/537.36'})
  print(driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;"))

  # Setting user agent as Chrome/79.0.3945.130
  driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36'})
  print(driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;"))

  # Setting user agent as Chrome/79.0.3945.0
  driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.0 Safari/537.36'})
  print(driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;"))

  # Setting user agent as Chrome/79.0.3945.117
  driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36'})
  print(driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;"))

  # Setting user agent as Chrome/79.0.3945.88
  driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36'})
  print(driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Default UserAgent is: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.101 Safari/537.36
  Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; Generic Android-x86_64 Build/QD1A.190821.014.C2; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/79.0.3945.36 Safari/537.36
  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36
  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.0 Safari/537.36
  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36
  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36
  ```

Comment: You're right, thank you. This worked perfectly fine. Only 2 questions arised, are we able to change the useragent to another version of chrome using this function? And would it be possible (in case of botting multiple instances) to use change the user agent to more than 3/4 different fingerprints? Thank you for your time btw.

Comment: @YoramYoutube Ofcoarse you can, why not?